# Switching to another view on the UITabBarController and then activating a selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a button on one of my views and I want it to open another view from the tab bar (the view has already been loaded by the app delegate) and then activate one of that view's selectors, which opens a UIActionSheet. This is what I'm doing so far for switching to the other view:

```
- (void)btnOpenOtherViewPressed:(id)sender
{   
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];
}
```

This brings me to the other window, but I can't find a way of sending a signal to the other view controller saying I want to open the UIActionSheet when switching to the view by pressing that button rather than using the tab bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use notification for this message passing:

```
- (void)btnOpenOtherViewPressed:(id)sender
{   
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"btnOpenOtherViewPressed" object:nil];
}
```

Add this code to destination view in viewDidLoad:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showActionSheet:) name:@"btnOpenOtherViewPressed" object:nil];
```

And add this method:

```
-(void)showActionSheet:(NSNotification *)notification{

}
```